# Passing object with an array in it from java to c

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am writing app on android studio IDE.
I need to do some computation really fast and considering using NDK.
I have a Java class with a double array in it.

Class X{
…
double []g =new double[1000];
…
}

I want to pass an object of this class, X,  to c thought NDK and use array g elements. While I know how to do so for single parameters, I couldn’t find any example for an (double)  array (the g array in the example above).

If this is possible for Andorid Studio IDE, I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: just create a native method that takes `double[]` parameter

Comment: Thnaks. I know how to do that. But I want to use an object of the class, because my next step is to use array of objects as X.

Comment: `"While I know how to do so for single parameters, I couldn’t find any example for an (double) array"` so you know how to pass double array or not?

Comment: I dont know how to access array inside a class, after it object is passed to C!

Comment: see `*DoubleArray*` methods

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: http://leo.ugr.es/elvira/devel/Tutorial/Java/native1.1/implementing/array.html